# Continuity of $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$ on $(-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, power-series

If the series $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n$ converges, does it follow that the power series $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$ converge to a continuous function on $(-1,1)$?

Will showing uniform convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$ help?

Comment: Yes and yes. I am quite sure you can easily prove uniform convergence on $[-r,r]$, $1>r >0$. And from Abel’s theorem (iirc) the series is defined and left continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @Mindlack Abel says that *if* it defined on 1, it is left continuous there

Comment: @Mindlack I don't  know of Abel's theorem. Can it be proved in some other way?

Answer (score 3):

For $|x| \leq 1-\epsilon$ the series $\sum |a_n| |x^{n}|$ is dominated by the convergent series $C(1-\epsilon)^{n}$ where $C=\sup ]\{|a_n|:n\geq 1\}$. By M-test, the given series converges uniformly for $|x| \leq 1-\epsilon$ and hence its sum is continuous there. Since $\epsilon $ is arbitrary we are done. Note that $C <\infty$ because $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: But we do not have that $a_n$ is absolutely convergent

Comment: He doesn't use that $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely anywhere (instead, he proves that $\sum a_nx^n$ converges absolutely and uniformly for $|x|\leq1-\varepsilon$).

Comment: @Matematleta The question has nothing to do with convergence at $x=-1$.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question. I deleted my comment. I thought the OP was asking about convergence at the boundary. The more interesting fact is that if $\sum a_n$ converges then $f(x)\to \sum a_n$ as $x\to 1.$